# What is the meaning of Delta in the discrete sample size formula?

Tags: statistics

The following excerpt is taken from [the Six Sigma Institute website](https://www.sixsigma-institute.org/Six_Sigma_DMAIC_Process_Measure_Phase_Data_Collection_Strategy_Sampling.php)

[image: Six Sigma Sample Size Formula - Discrete Data]

I can't understand what Delta represents in this formula.

First, considering example (2) on their page, they have used this formula to calculate that a sample size of 865 is required in order to estimate proportion defective to within 2%.  For this to work you need a handle on the defect rate to begin with, which they have estimated as 10%.  OK... so does this mean that with a sample size of 865 I should expect defect rates somewhere between 8% and 12% in practice?

If this is true, then I can't understand example (1).  If I plug these values back here to get delta (n = 865, P = 0.1) then I get a delta value of 50.

I am obviously completely misunderstanding this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can firstly solve the formula in general for $\Delta$.

$ n=\left(\frac{1.96}{\Delta} \right)^2\cdot p\cdot (1-p)$

$n=\frac{\left(1.96\sigma\right)^2}{\Delta^2}$

*Multiplying both sides by $\Delta^2$ and dividing both sides by $n$*.

$\Delta^2=\frac{\left(1.96\right)^2}{n}\cdot p\cdot (1-p)$

*Taking square root*

$\Delta=1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{p\cdot (1-p)}{ n}}$

Plugging in your numbers

$$ \Delta=1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{0.1\cdot 0.9}{ 865}}=0.01999...\approx 0.02$$

Comment: Of course, you are right about the transposition.  I had taken this for granted in the original article and assumed my understanding was faulty.

So, basically, their example (1) is incorrect because they got the transposition wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. They divide it by $1.96^2$ instead of multiplying it.

Comment: I have no choice than to give you the accepted answer to my very stupid question! Thank you!

I also wrote a quick program to chekc the validity of the formula itself, the calculated N or Delta values seem to be OK.  So it was only their mistake that was the problem, the formula itself is OK.

Comment: @Q'' Stupid questions don't exist.